# When converted to json by Golang's Marshal, the array part becomes an object, so I want to keep the array

Tags: go

#### What I want to do

- Convert `{"color": "red", "mrkdwn_in":["text"]}` in json to a structure with UnMarshal
- Change "color" from 'red' to 'blue'
- Change the changed structure to json with Marshal
- The original `"mrkdwn_in":["text"]}` is not well preserved.

  - It becomes `"mrkdwn_in":[{"text":""}]` or `"mrkdwn_in":""`.
- I want to keep the "mrkdwn_in" part in its original state.

#### code

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type TestStruct struct {
    Color        string       `json:"color"`
    MrkdwnIn     []MrkdwnIn   `json:"mrkdwn_in"`
}

type MrkdwnIn struct {
    Text string `json:"text"`
}

func main() {
    jsonData1 := "{\"color\":\"red\",\"mrkdwn_in\":[\"text\"]}"
    var body TestStruct
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonData1), &body)
    body.Color = "blue"
    var jsonData2 []byte
    jsonData2, _ = json.Marshal(body)

    jsonDataText := string(jsonData2)
    fmt.Println(jsonDataText)
}
```

#### Execution result of the above code

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is obvious

```
MrkdwnIn     []MrkdwnIn   `json:"mrkdwn_in"`
```

MrkdwnIn is a array of object

```
MrkdwnIn     []string`json:"mrkdwn_in"`
```

MrkdwnIn should be a array of string